# Replace [url=URL] regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

looking for a way to remove any text that is

```
[url=]
```

That would be easy, but the url itself is a URL I dont have control of.

e.g or urls:

[url=wqffqwfq]
   [url=qwfwqfqf]

etc.

Looking for a preg replace, currently have this:

```
$post_text = preg_replace('%\[URL[^\]]*\][^\[\]]*|\[/URL[^\]]*\]%i', '', $post_text);
```

But that removes the image that comes after the url.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this regex `"/[url(.*?)]/i"`?

Comment: You can also try ```"@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?).*$)@";```.

Comment: Can you give us an example with the worst situation, meanwhile I think you should try what @charlotte Dunois said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you use too much escape characters. You can however use lazy capture groups:

```
$string = '[foo] buz [url=wqffqwfq] qux [bar] foobar [url=qwfwqfqf] faq';
$pattern = '/\[url=(.*?)\]/i';
$replace = '';
$string = preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$string);
//$string = '[foo] buz  qux [bar] foobar  faq';
```

If the assignment (`=`) character is optional, you can use the `/\[url(.*?)\]/i` pattern.

Information: `.*?` means a non-greedy capture: this means that `.` is captures, as long as there is no way to escape the group. From the moment it is possible, the regex mechanism escapes the group.